# Autoregressive model in R

Tags: r, autoregressive, unevenly-spaced-time-series, nls

Citation:

> As the data represent repeated measurements from individual plots,
>   within-plot correlation may result in inefficient estimates and
>   underestimation of standard error. Therefore the error term (o) was
>   explicitly modeled using a first order autoregressive model that
>   accommodates for the irregular spacing of measurements.

[image]

> where e(i, T) is the error at the ith sample plot at age T, a is the time since the previous measurement, p is a coefficient of correlation between measurements one year apart and u(i)s are normally and independently distributed random errors.

Authors wrote that they used ordinary nonlinear last squares procedure.
How do I incorporate such error statement into nonlinear last squares procedure (`nls`) in R?

Comment: the nlme package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlme/nlme.pdf) has an autoregressive covariance structure which you presumably could use.

Comment: I know that it is. But in the article later on they write that parameter were estimated using ordinary nonlinear last square procedure. Is it possible to do it by nlme???

Comment: It is somewhat unclear what you are lookimg for. I suggest you explain the analysis a bit more in detail, it will increase the likelihood of getting guidance

Comment: @Legionista: You can use `nlme` with no random effects, in which case I think it does what you want. As Adam asks, what is the bigger picture of your question: are you simply trying to replicate their findings, or is there more to this?